# create a single task user in windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, batch-file, user

I have a program that I want to run automatically whenever a specific user logs in to their Windows account.
Additionally, I only want my program to run and nothing else, like the desktop or Windows Explorer.

In other words, I want to create a single-task user environment.
I think need to write a batch file to achieve this, but I am unsure how to do it.

Can anyone guide me on how to create a batch file that will launch my program upon login and restrict other programs from starting up?

Comment: Google how to replace the shell. Its a registry setting. It will now say shell=explorer.exe. Replace that by shell=myprogram.exe and you accomplish exactly what you want. But other programs can still be launched if your program allows that. If you want to absolutely block everything, look into a kiosk solution.

Comment: You're trying to re-invent the kiosk mode. Google for it.